# Excel Copy a range of cell values to the clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy a range of cell (values only/ text) to the clipboard so the user does not have to do a paste special values only when they paste them into another spreadsheet.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With New DataObject
        .SetText Range("A32:Q32").Text
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
    'Range("A32:Q32").Copy
End Sub
```

This gives me a runtime error

> 94 Invalid use of Null

If I just use the commented out code `Range.("A32:Q32").Copy` it copies the formulas and unless the user does the special paste they get all kinds of reference errors.

Comment: Both answers worked. One answered my original need, the second came up with an even slicker way to do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit convoluted, but get text > clear clipboard > put text back :

```
[A32:Q32].Copy
With New DataObject
    .GetFromClipboard
    s = .GetText
    .Clear
    .SetText s
    .PutInClipboard
End With
```

`Range.Text` returns `Null` when the individual cell texts in the range are different.

Comment: It appears that the `Application.CutCopyMode = False` is not needed as the clipboard contents are overwritten with the `.PutInClipboard`

Comment: @gbarnabic if I remember correctly, if you paste in the same Excel Application instance while the copy area is still active, Excel can ignore the clipboard and just use the cut/copy range

Comment: @gbarnabic you are right .. the cut/copy selection disappears after the `.PutInClipboard`

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know dataobject, so I propose a workaround by having the user select the destination cell, too

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim userRng As Range
    With ActiveSheet 'reference currently active sheet, before the user could change it via inputbox 
        Set userRange = GetUserRange()
        If Not userRange Is Nothing Then ' if the user chose a valid range
            With .Range("A32:Q32")
                userRange.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value =.Value ' paste values only
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Function GetUserRange() As Range   
' adapted from http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/pausing_a_macro_to_get_a_user_selected_range/

    Prompt = "Select a cell for the output."
    Title = "Select a cell"

    '   Display the Input Box
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetUserRange = Application.InputBox( _
        Prompt:=Prompt, _
        Title:=Title, _
        Default:=ActiveCell.Address, _
        Type:=8) 'Range selection

'   Was the Input Box canceled?
    If GetUserRange Is Nothing Then MsgBox “Canceled!”
End Function
```

Comment: Not what I asked but I ended up using it.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. So which solution did you actually adopted?

Comment: I actually used both.  I copied the range to the clipboard then I implemented your code. At the prompt I indicated that the data was copied to the clipboard, but if they wanted they could select a cell to paste it.  As I have found out doing it within the VBA code clears the "Undo buffer" so there is no going back.  With the clipboard method the, Ctrl-Z works of they paste to the wrong place.  I figured I would let the user choose which method.